# terraform formatlist to add SSH private key

Tags: yaml, terraform

I need to add a private ssh-key to a yaml config file. I need to do this with terraform.

I need this format:

```
              privateKey: |
                -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
                b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABFwAAAAdzc2gtcn
```

I tried the following with formatlist function.

```
resource "local_file" "jenkins_yaml" {
  filename = "${path.cwd}/${path.module}/jenkins.yaml"
  content = templatefile("${path.cwd}/${path.module}/templates/jenkins.yaml.tpl", {

   PRIVATE_KEY_TEST = formatlist("                %s\n", [data.ansiblevault_path.private_key.value])

  })
}
```

with this template

```
              privateKey: |
%{ for line in PRIVATE_KEY_TEST ~}${line}%{ endfor ~}
```

But this only works for the first line shown here:

```
              privateKey: |
                -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAABFwAAAAdzc2gtcn
```

How can I achive to have all the lines with the correct space in front?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution which is very simple. It's all about the formating in the template file with the right indentations.

```
              privateKey: |
%{ for line in PRIVATE_KEY_TEST ~}
                ${line}
%{ endfor ~}
```

and of course in the terraform file we need to split the lines after each newline.

```
resource "local_file" "jenkins_yaml" {
  filename = "${path.cwd}/${path.module}/jenkins.yaml"
  content = templatefile("${path.cwd}/${path.module}/templates/jenkins.yaml.tpl", {

    PRIVATE_KEY_TEST = split("\n", data.ansiblevault_path.private_key.value)
  })
}
```